# Decoding manchester line coding to original signal

Tags: networking, encoding, network-security

Sorry for this homework type question,but I have been trying this question since long,and I haven't got an approach in my head.

[image]

I have tried searching the internet for line decoding (the opposite of line encoding),but haven't got any appreciable results. Can anyone help?